# How much free memory space should be left for good website operation?

Tags: memory-management, production-environment

I've been told that swap mem should never be used for the best shape of server's sake.

So how much free memory space should be left for good when the server is running in the high traffic time?

For a 8GB server, 1G free? Or if it's ok with 100M free?

Comment: This question will get a better response on serverfault. It would help to add your setup/environment/os details too.

Comment: Can I move this to serverfault?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, if you use swap memory that means you use a virtual memory(i.e. a file on your Hard drive) when phisical(RAM) is not enough, it is around 1000 times slower (but is 100 times cheaper). If you use a Solid State Drive (SSD) this slow down is less noticeable, because in essence SSD's are based on semiconductor chips and storage area is positioned on NAND flash memory instead of spinning magnetic disc plates (that`s why it is much faster).

It is adviseable in any moment to have at least 10% free space, no matter what storage you use, in your case 10% from 8GB = 800MB